# Mounting LGA1366 Xeon w3680 on a motherboard

Tags: cooling, computer-building, xeon

I am putting a home server/workstation together and am having a hard time mounting a Xeon W3680 onto a Supermicro MBD-X8DTH-6F-O board. Its the first time in a good 10 years that I assemble a machine from parts, and this problem has totally got me by surprise.

The root of the problem is that the stock cooling the Xeon shipped with uses a screw-less mounting system, but the motherboard I have uses screws. I see no way to remove the screw holes (and X assembly on the back of the board) and so I wonder whether I should buy cooling that uses such a screw assembly, and if yes, which cooling set should I get? From my searching, it looks like most of the cooling assemblies use this new style of mounting. Any pointers?

The mount on the board:

[image: The mount on the board]

The base of the cooler itself:

[image: The base of the cooler itself]

- This is the [CPU in question](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117242)
- This is the [board in question](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182174)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, LGA1366 is not universally applied. Standard LGA1366 Xeons are supposed to use the screw mounting.  Core i-series LGA1366 kits do not, on the other hand.

The problem here is that the W3680 (which I am not familiar with and unfortunately I can't find good specs on right now) is apparently not a true Xeon but just a rebranded Core i7 part, because 1366 Xeons that I'm familiar with do not COME with stock coolers (the Intel ones are insufficient).

There no way you'll be able to mount that cooler to this board; you need to get either a standard single processor LGA1366 desktop board, or more likely get another heatsink.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll hop out to a neighborhood computer store and try to get a cooler, should I not find one, I'll probably return the CPUs and get proper Xeons.

Comment: @krypticmind - The chips will probably work fine and six-core Xeons can get a bit pricey, so it may be worth ordering decent coolers.  YMMV. --- EDIT: I take that bad, it looks like these chips are single-processor only! They won't work if you're planning to use two.  That further affirms my belief that they're just i7s.

Answer (score 1):

The  W3680 is a SINGLE cpu Xeon.  You cannot run 2 on the same board.  So they have the mounts of a stock 1366 socket( single processor) board.